# laravel 5.1 says for all the other routes that except ('/') that 404 page not found on online Amazon Server using ec2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-5

Hi i have installed the laravel on ec2 instance using this video

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ARpTKWc6lQ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ARpTKWc6lQ)

I have changed the document root path from  `/var/www`
 to `/var/www/html/laravel/public` 
 in the deafult.conf file as described at the end of the video 

But now my when i open my website my homepage http://52.26.133.246/ which have `('/')` shows fine but when i open my other page with routes like `('AdminApp')` or you can simple click on admin link on the navbar of home page with whole link is  http://52.26.133.246/AdminApp it says 

`404 page not found`
and also

```
The requested URL /AdminApp was not found on this server.
```

but when i use /index.php in the url the page is shown 
here is the link
http://52.26.133.246/index.php/AdminApp

Also kindly check this link also to without `index.php`

```
http://52.26.133.246/welcome
```

with index.php

```
http://52.26.133.246/index.php/welcome
```

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: server needs mod_rewrite extension

Comment: @KiranLM how can i do that i am beginner to .htaccess and mods and file permissions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and

Check your etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file. 
It should have the following in it:

```
AllowOverride None
```

change it to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Kiran LM i am using cygwin i am in this directory /var/www/html/laravel i have used this command  cd etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf but it says to me No such file or directory kindly help me..

Comment: move to root directory by `cd /` and then `cd etc/httpd/conf/`, list directory `dir` or `ls` and make sure that there is `httpd.conf`

Comment: Kirna LM cd for command etc/httpd/conf/ it says No such file or directory

Comment: put a `/` before `etc` => `cd /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: it still gives me this error No such file or directory

Comment: No it dont give this error it takes to the directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84004/discussion-between-kiran-lm-and-usama).