# Laravel - 404 Not found every page except homepage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, wamp

I'm newbie on Laravel. I'm using Laravel 5 - Wamp on Windows 8. Every page on my localhost have 404 not found error except homepage. Although I can access them with index.php .
For example URL is :

http://localhost/mpr/public/index.php/register

is okay. Actually

http://localhost/mpr/public/register

has an error (404 not found).

I've checked rewrite_module but it was not changed. Any suggestion?

Comment: can you check on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570733/laravel-5-1-says-for-all-the-other-routes-that-except-that-404-page-not-fo

Comment: check this all are the active in your wamp
    PHP >= 5.5.9,
    OpenSSL PHP Extension,
    PDO PHP Extension,
    Mbstring PHP Extension,
    Tokenizer PHP Extension,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On command prompt, go to your laravel folder,

```
cd C:/wamp/www/laravel-app-folder
```

and run

```
php artisan serve.
```

Now try to access your app on `localhost:8000`

Now, you will be able to access your routes like `localhost:8000/register`

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I can access my routes , Why I can't access my route with localhost/laravel-app-folder/register?

Comment: Because, laravel needs a separate local server to run. You can use your wamp to configure for that, but this is simple and easy approach.

Answer (score 2):

Go in .htaccess file and add this line

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And if not present .htaccess file in public folder then you have to upload .htaccess file and add this line of the code after then you will find the remove error

Answer (score 0):

It is rewrite mode issue.

Go to `wamp/bin/apache/apache2423/conf/httpd.conf`
    and remove `hash<#>` from `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` this line.

Now you can access all pages.